# Can an ASP.NET vNext application be hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I'm struggling to workout how to host a local ASP.NET vNext application in IIS. Is this possible currently or is just selfhosting or IISExpress available. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Where in the process are you struggling? What type of project do you have? Can you show us your project.json file?

Comment: @AndersNS Its more basic than that. I'm just starting off and cannot see how to start. All the docs I've seen are for IISExpress i'm not sure how to point to my local iis etc

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'kpm pack' to create a package and then drop that in the wwwroot folder. Create an application in the IIS Manager. Refer to the 'using command line' section in the below link to create the packaged web project https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/FTP-deploy-an-AspNet-vNext-application-to-Microsoft-Azure-websites

You can also right click a project in VS14 and click Publish, then choose Filesystem in the dialogue.

Comment: OK so its quite a manual process in the current build,which will need repeating every time you make development changes. IISexpress will do until either VS bootstraps this process or the next version of IIS ?

Comment: @Anuraj: With latest CTP tooling we support publish from VS. I'll check why the link is not working anymore

Comment: Thanks Suhas :) I got it resolved I found another link under pages - https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Deploy-an-AspNet-vNext-application-to-Microsoft-Azure-websites and I did a blog post on the same http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-host-asp-net-5-application-in-azure-web-apps/

Comment: That link is broken also :(

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I deployed my app in my local IIS server.

As you can see publish vNext to local system generate two folders approot and wwwroot
You should copy these 2 folders on IIS and specify folder wwwroot as Site Folder